# what is alternative for SITE command of ftp in sftp

Tags: linux, sftp, mainframe

I am trying to connect to a mainframe from linux server using `sftp` command and execute a SITE command and transfer file to mainframe, but it is failing and showing Invalid command.

I am using batch operation mode as `sftp -b $batch_file user@remote_user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent of FTP's `SITE` command in SFTP.  SFTP uses a binary format for its protocol messages, and uses specific request *numbers* (or IDs) to indicate the desired operation.  And SFTP does not define any request number/ID for "execute this string as a command".  *SSH* can be used for that sort of thing, but not *SFTP*.

Comment: I am setting `RECFM=FB` and `LRECL` is there any way that it could be done through sftp

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  The closest doc I could find is [this one](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.foto100/sftpmvs.htm), from the same site which describes the `RECFM` command, but I'm not sure that will help you.